# Equivalence of definitions of infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am familiar with the concept infinite dimensional vector spaces and some examples of them, but I am a little confused about how to define when a vector space is in fact of infinite dimension.

The straight-forward approach is to show that the space cannot have a finite dimension, but I can think of two ways to go about this:

> 1. A vector space $V$ is said to be of infinite dimension if it has an infinite linearly-independent subset.
> 2. A vector space $V$ is said to be of infinite dimension if it has a linearly-independent set of size $n$ for every natural number $n$.

The first condition seems the most natural one, and obviously implies the second. On the other hand, the second condition ought to suffice as well, otherwise the notion of dimension would make little sense.

Does the second condition in fact imply the first?

Comment: Yes, if you accept principles like Dependent Choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for a vector space $ V$ the second condition holds. I'm going to prove the first by building a chain $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \cdots $ of linear independent sets where each $A_i $ has size $ i$. It is clear that you can peak an element $v\neq 0 $ in $ V$ since for the zero space the second condition does not hold. Let $ A_1$ be the set $ \{a_1\}$ Now assume you had built linear independent sets $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_n $ each of the size of the index. You know that the sub space generated by $ A_n$ is not $ V$ because $Span A_n $ does not contain linear independent sets of size $n+1 $. Teherefore you can complete to a base $ A_n \cup S$ and $ A_n \subsetneq S\cup A_n$. Choose an element $ a'\in A_n \cup S$ which is not in $A_n$, then $A_{n+1} :=A_n\cup \{a'\}$  is linear independent and $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_{n+1} $.
It is easy to check that $ A=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$ is a linear independent set and it is not finite.